# Djongo takes wrong Database URL

Tags: python, django, mongodb, docker

I'm using djong (mongodb) as my database backend for a django application.

I configured in the settings.py :

```
'HOST': '172.17.0.2',
        'PORT': 27017
```

(172.17.0.2) is the ip of the docker container the mongodb is running in.

If I now run `python3 manage.py runserver`

I get the error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

which makes sense because the mongodb is not runnig on localhost.

But why dows pymongo think that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure it will solve your problem, but I see a mistake in your file according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/) : you should have quotes around 27017.

```
        'HOST': '172.17.0.2',
        'PORT': '27017'
```

Comment: Sorry… Then I don’t krow :-(

Comment: Do you have the same behavior by running `python3 manage.py runserver 172.17.0.2:27017` ?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo

```
'ENGINE': 'djongo',
'NAME': 'my_project',
'CLIENT': {
    'host': 'your_mongo_host',
}
```